# best way to share has_and_belongs_to_many between multiple moles rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, database-migration, rails-migrations

So currently I've got a category and an article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Which works fine. But now I want to extend the system and introduce other models that will also be assigned categories in a similar way like:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I'm wondering, rather than create new join tables for each model, is it possible to share a single join table? Or is this actually the more preferable approach, and if so why?

Comment: I would still go for seperate tables. A join table only has two columns and not using polymorphic association gives you real foreign key constraints, better joins etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [polymorphic associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). But that doesn't work with `has_and_belongs_to_many` so we need to set up the many-to-many relationship manually. See [this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564463/polymorphic-has-and-belongs-to-many).

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_relations
end

class CategoryRelation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categories
  belongs_to :categorable, polymorphic: true
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_relations, as: categorable
  has_many :categories, through: :category_relations
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_relations, as: categorable
  has_many :categories, through: :category_relations
end
```

And the migration would look something like...

```
class CreateCategorable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :categories_relations, id: false do |t|
      t.references :categories, index: true
      t.references :categorable, polymorphic: true, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

`t.references :categorable, polymorphic: true, index: true` is a convenience method which sets up `t.bigint  :categorable_id` and `t.string :categorable_type` to store both the ID and class of the relationship. `categorable_type: 'Article', categorable_id: 5` references the Article with an ID of 5.

Since it's many-to-many, no modification to `articles` nor `projects` tables are necessary.

Polymorphic associations are convenient, but because it does not use foreign keys the database cannot enforce referential integrity. That is handled by Rails. This is acceptable in a Rails application because the database is usually only ever controlled by the Rails model. The Rails model and the database can be considered a single unit.